# Connecting points via network layer?

Tags: network

I have a set of points which are bus stops in a network separately. I also have a layer of road network. These bus stop points and the nodes of the network perfectly match so there is no need for alignment.

I want to perform the following tasks:

1. Filter only the bus network out of the entire road network: For this I want to connect all the points through the network layer
2. Create a separate attribute naming each bus route in that bus network.

Comment: As a relatively new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  As you will see in the tour there should be only one question asked per question.  What GIS software are you using?